# Implementar Select que contenga años - Laravel

Tags: laravel, php7, laravel-7

Buenas estoy tratando de implementar un select, que el usuario pueda seleccionar de 0 a 5 años de 5 a 10 , de 10 a 20 y la verdad no encuentro manera de hacerlo, y como guardaria tales valores en la bd actualmente tengo un foreach que recorre los años pero me pidieron un cambio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <select id="year" class="form-control" name="antiquity">
                        <option selected>Antiguedad ...</option>
                        <option value=""></option>
                        {{ $year = date('Y') }}
                        @for ($year = -2020; $year <= -1990; $year++) <option value="{{ $year }}">{{ $year }}</option>
                            @endfor
                    </select>
                </div>
```

Comment: Puedes utilizar carbon con la funcion diffInYears

Comment: Y que tipo de dato es la columna donde almacenarás esos valores?

Comment: la tengo como string

Comment: Y entonces para que generarlos con un foreach si guradaras un string de año más texto?

Comment: Lo que quiero saber es como generar tal select, porque a la hora de que hagan una consulta para ver las propiedades de esos años